# In Java how do you pass a String format variable placeholder to another String formatter?

Tags: java, string, format

I have a String formatter like this:

```
String testLogMessage = String.format("testing %s scenario %s", "BIG");
logger.info(String.format(testLogMessage, 1));
```

I have several tests and want to pass a number into my testLogMessage.  At runtime I get this exception:

```
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
```

I could use a second string formatter, but is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first call to `String.format` expects both placeholders to be satisfied, but you only pass one value, prompting the exception.

To have the *resulting* string contain a placeholder for the next call to `String.format`, you can [escape the `%` sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) with another `%` sign.

> '%'   percent The result is a literal '%' ('\u0025')

```
String testLogMessage = String.format("testing %s scenario %%s", "BIG");
```

This will result in the string `"testing BIG scenario %s"`, which you can use in the second `String.format` call.  You'll want it to be a `%d` so you can pass an `int`.

```
String testLogMessage = String.format("testing %s scenario %%d", "BIG");
```